# Time to completion for a simple catalytic process involving two types of ideal gas molecules

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Imagine we have two types of gas molecules diffusing in a chamber - those of type $A$ and those of type $B$.  When two gas molecules collide, we have something akin to a simple catalytic reaction where: $A + B \to B + C$, s.t. $B$ catalyzes the transformation of $A$ to some form $C$ but itself remains unchanged.

Now imagine we're in a chamber with some number of gas molecules $n_A$ of type $A$ and some number of gas molecules $n_B$ of type $B$.  I also tell you the rate $\lambda$ at which two lone gas molecules, one of type $A$ and one of type $B$, will collide if they are the only gas molecules in the chamber, and a probability $p$ that a collision will result in the aforementioned reaction.  Imagine also that the number of copies of the gas molecule $C$ does not influence the values for $\lambda$ or $p$.

To keep things as simple as possible, let's assume also that: (1) If we keep our eyes on a particular pair of gas molecules (one of type $A$ and one of type $B$) their collision rate will still be $\approx \lambda$ regardless of the concentration of other gas molecules in the chamber; (2) the $A + B \to B + C$ is instantaneous, taking an arbitrarily small amount of time.

What is the probability distribution for the expected time to convert all molecules of type $A$ to molecules of type $C$?  What is my expected time to some % conversion of molecules of type $A$ to molecules of type $C$?

I suppose the follow-up question I have is: if we assume that, conditioned on two molecules $A$ and $B$ bumping into one another AND the reaction proceeding (which occurs with probability $p$ per collision between $A$ and $B$) how do we calculate the above distribution and expected time to % completion if we assume that the reaction proceeds through some (inert / incapable of reacting with anything else) interaction complex with an exponentially distributed lifetime $\lambda_c$?

Note: Of course I'm aware of Michaelis–Menten kinetic models (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michaelis%E2%80%93Menten_kinetics), however I'm never seen a good intuitive treatment for the "time to completion" for an enzymatic reaction like the one described above.  I'd like to walk away from this question knowing better, for example, how this time to % completion scales if we hold the catalyst concentration / count constant and scale the concentration / count of the substrate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rate at which molecules of type A disappear when there are $k$ molecules of type A and $n_B$ molecules of type B is $kp\lambda n_B$ hence the time for every molecule of type A to disappear is the sum of independent exponential random variables of parameters $kp\lambda n_B$, from $k=1$ to $k=n_A$. Likewise, for every $x$ in $(0,1)$, the time for a proportion $x\%$ of molecules of type A to disappear is the sum of $n_A$ independent exponential random variables of parameters $kp\lambda n_B$, from $k=(1-x)n_A$ to $k=n_A$. The expectation of the time of complete disappearance is
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n_A}\frac1{kp\lambda n_B}\approx\frac{\log n_A}{p\lambda n_B},
$$
and the expectation of the time of disappearance of $x\%$ is
$$
\sum_{k=(1-x)n_A}^{n_A}\frac1{kp\lambda n_B}\approx\frac{-\log(1-x)}{p\lambda n_B}.
$$
Both approximations are in the limit $n_A\to\infty$.

Comment: The LHS are exact formulas hence one can use them in the limits one is interested in.

Comment: ((Comment from the OP now deleted.))

Comment: How might we modify this if there was a constant time penalty $T$ for each collision between $A$ and $B$, regardless of whether $A$ is transformed (with probability $p$)?

Comment: I deleted my question because I realized you have provided the exact expressions, which would allow me to take the appropriate limit.  However, the thanks for the answer remains!

Comment: I deleted my (earlier comment) not question!

Comment: What is a time penalty?

Comment: I mean "time delay" in the sense that when $A$ and $B$ interact (and with probability $p$, $A$ becomes $C$, and probability $(1-p)$ nothing occurs) there's some time $T$ involved before $B$ can interact with another $A$ regardless of what occurs.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the time of disappearance of $k$ molecules with delay $T$ is simply $kT$ plus the time of disappearance of $k$ molecules with no delay.

Comment: Actually, it's going to become a mess in any case, right?  Because while $A$ and $B$ are bound together, $B$ is not available to interact with any other $A$ molecules.

Comment: Then add $n_AT/p$ to the mean time without delay.

Comment: But isn't there a problem here in the sense that, with any delay, the amount of free $B$ will depend on the count for $A$?

Comment: The probability at any given time that a (specific) molecule $A$ is annihilated is independent of $n_A$.  A delay would change that, right?